# Появление div после заполнения input

Tags: javascript, html, input

подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующее действие:
есть input, вот код

```
<input class="field" id="number" type="text" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000">
```

после того, как в него будет введено 11 символов и более, нужно ,чтобы появлялся этот блок:

```
<div class="ccd"><a href="#" class="ddott">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
```

мне подсказали, что часть реализации делается так:

```
$(селектор поля).on("input",function() {if(this.value.length > 10)показывайте свой div});
```

не могу додуматься до конца...буду благодарен

Comment: Вам уже подсказали все что нужно для реализации, дальше нужно подумать самостоятельно или сходить на сайты фрилансеров :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
number.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  let length = this.value.length
  if (length > 10) {
    document.querySelector(".ccd").style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
.ccd {
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="field" id="number" type="text" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000">
<div class="ccd"><a href="#" class="ddott">ДАЛЕЕ</a></div>
```